# Sql server select three different rows in same table with one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 column(ID and SPAN) and three different rows with ID as 1,2,3. The table looks as below:

```
ID      SPAN
1       30
2       -30
3       -7
```

I need to get these SPAN for various ID.

```
DECLARE @LeadLookUpSpan SMALLINT, @NotificationResendSpan SMALLINT;
SELECT @LeadLookUpSpan = Span FROM UsedCarNotificationConfig where Id=2;
SELECT @NotificationResendSpan = Span FROM UsedCarNotificationConfig where Id=3;
```

I am doing SELECT from table that would check each row everytime. Can anyone help me optimize this query so that i can retrieve all Span for multiple Id in one go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
DECLARE @LeadLookUpSpan SMALLINT, @NotificationResendSpan SMALLINT;

SELECT 
    @LeadLookUpSpan         = MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 2 THEN Span END),
    @NotificationResendSpan = MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 3 THEN Span END)
FROM UsedCarNotificationConfig
WHERE 
    Id IN(2, 3);
```

Comment: Why are you using MAX here?

Comment: To PIVOT the data. The technique is called conditional aggregation. This will work assuming there is only one record for each `Id`.